# django model Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.4

I am upgrading one of my Django project from 1.2 to 1.6.6. I encountered `Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field` error when I trying to call Model Member. It seems like that all fields wrapped with a "wrap_model" are not recognized. Here is the code for `wrap_model()`

```
def wrap_model(o):
    from django.conf import settings
    FIELD_LABELS=getattr(settings,'MODEL_FIELDS',{})
    object_name=o._meta.object_name
    if FIELD_LABELS:
        for f in o._meta.local_fields:
            fl=None
            full_field_name='%s__%s' % (object_name,f.name)  
            if full_field_name in FIELD_LABELS:
                fl=FIELD_LABELS[full_field_name]
            elif f.name in FIELD_LABELS:
                fl=FIELD_LABELS[f.name]
            if fl:
                if isinstance(fl,dict):
                    for k,v in list(fl.items()):
                        setattr(f,k,v)
            else:
                f.verbose_name=fl
    return o
```

And here is the code for my model

```
@wrap_model
class Member(models.Model):
    username = wrap(
        models.EmailField(
            _('Email:'), unique=True), size='50'
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        _('Password:'),
        max_length=50,
        help_text='(type and retype password to change)'
    )
    title = wrap(
        models.CharField(
            _('Title'),
            max_length=50,
            null=True,
            default='',
            blank=True
        ),
        size='50'
    )
    fname = wrap(
        models.CharField(
            _('First Name:'),
            max_length=50,
            null=False,
            default=''
        ),
        size='25',
        grp=1
    )
    lname = wrap(
        models.CharField(
            _('Last Name:'),
            max_length=50,
            null=False,
            default=''
        ),
        size='25',
        grp=2
    )    
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        editable=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        auto_now=True
    )
    accessed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Apparently those fields wrapped with `wrap_model()` function are not recognized while fields without wrapper (such as created, modified, accessed) are normal. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the `wrap` function?

Comment: Since you're only moving to 1.6, I'd suggest looking into South to create this migration. Better to make a clean separation between your old model code and your new model code and leave the migrating up to South. http://south.aeracode.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is an indent error in the wrap() function. The correctly indented code should be like this

```
def wrap(obj, widget=None, clean=None, format=None, grp=3, header='',**attrs):
    def formfield(**kwargs):
        "This makes sure the right properties get sent to form generator"
        form_class=obj.__class__.formfield(obj, **kwargs)
        if widget:
            defaults=dict(attrs=attrs)
        if obj.choices: defaults.update(choices=obj.choices)
        if format: defaults.update(format=format)
        form_class.widget=widget(**defaults)
        if hasattr(widget,'clean'):
            form_class.clean=widget.clean
        else:
            form_class.widget.attrs.update(**attrs)
        if clean:   form_class.clean=clean
        form_class.grp=grp
        form_class.header=header
        return form_class
    if widget or clean or attrs:
        obj.formfield=formfield
    return obj
```